# Error while trying to configure ArangoDB replication

Tags: replication, arangodb

While trying to configure an async replication on an ArangoDB database (using the document https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/dd912dcaec4843f15ce230c477a83ac90052c2bf/Documentation/Books/Manual/Administration/Replication/Asynchronous/Components.md) I got this error:

```
JavaScript exception in file 
'/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/replication.js' at 209,7: 
ArangoError 1470: replication API is not supported on a coordinator
!      throw err;
!      ^
stacktrace: ArangoError: replication API is not supported on a coordinator
    at Object.exports.checkRequestResult 
(/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/arangosh.js:96:21)
    at waitForResult 
(/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/replication.js:207:16)
    at setup 
(/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/replication.js:310:10)
    at Object.setupReplication 
(/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/replication.js:313:51)
    at <shell command>:1:34
```

Any idea what could have caused it? I'm on the latest 3.3.3 version with a cluster up and running on 3 different machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing a coordinator. The replication API resides only on DB servers in an ArangoDB cluster. You will see a different behavior if you move to DB servers.